# How to remove loading when layer does not load by returning 0 feature

Tags: openlayers, layers, loading

I have a layer in Openlayers, and I showed a load while the layer doesn't load.

```
//show loading
my_layer.on("precompose", function () {
    document.getElementById("my_loader").classList.add("loader");
});         

//remove loading
my_layer.on("render", function () {
    document.getElementById("my_loader").classList.remove("loader");            
});
```

What happens is that this layer has a filter and it may not find the result, if you enter the value of the filter that does not exist. In this case, a layer does not load the data into the source and the "render" function is not executed.

How should I use the function to remove the load, even when the layer is not loaded because it contains size 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something similar to the example in https://openlayers.org/en/main/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html but add an extra test for `features.length == 0`

```
const vectorSource = new Vector({
  format: new GeoJSON(),
  loader: function(extent, resolution, projection, success, failure) {
     const proj = projection.getCode();
     const url = 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
         'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=osm:water_areas&' +
         'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=' + proj + '&' +
         'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',' + proj;
     const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('GET', url);
     const onError = function() {
       vectorSource.removeLoadedExtent(extent);
       failure();
     }
     xhr.onerror = onError;
     xhr.onload = function() {
       if (xhr.status == 200) {
         const features = vectorSource.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText);
         if (features.length == 0) {
           onError();
         } else {
           vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
           success(features);
         }
       } else {
         onError();
       }
     }
     xhr.send();
   },
   strategy: bbox,
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it adapted to my code and it's working as I need.